# Proving $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty \land f(x) $ is even $\Rightarrow \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = \infty $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, solution-verification

I realized that $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty \land f(x) $  is even $  \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = \infty $, and I tried to prove it. Is my proof valid?

Proof:

Given $ M > 0, \exists N \gt 0 $ such that $ \forall x \gt N, f(x) \gt M$. $ f(x) $ is even and therefore $ f(-x) > M, \forall x \gt M $. Therefore, $ f(x) \gt M, \forall x \lt -N $, which means $ \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = \infty$.

Comment: I think that's perfect. Good job

Comment: Why not N=M?  Different?

Comment: @herbsteinberg What do you mean?

Comment: @herbsteinberg $N$ is bound of $x$, $M$ is bound of $f(x)$. Similar to $\delta$ being bound of $x$ and $\epsilon$ being bound of $f(x)$ in continuous real analysis.

Comment: I misread the description.

Comment: Instead of going down to definition I would use $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(-x)=\lim_{t\to-\infty}f(t)$$ by application of the substitution $t=-x$ .

Comment: Shouldn't it be $f(-x) > M, \forall x> \color\red N$ in the second line of the proof?

Comment: @JuliusL33t You're right, a typo